# JavaScript forEach loop works in all webbrowser but Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, foreach

I've managed to get the loop working in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer (which doesn't seem to support forEach).

The JavaScript cpde:

```
function validate() {
    var msg = '';
    var i = 0;

    arr.forEach(
        function validateinfo(){
            if (getRBtnName('yesNo_' + i + '_0' == "" && 'yesNo_' + i + '_0') == "") {
                msg = 'Please select yes/no for all users'
            }
            if (msg == '') {
                return true;
            }
            is++;
        }
    )

    if (msg == '') {
        reloadpage();
    }

    if (msg != '') {
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }
}


function reloadpage(){
    window.location.reload()
}
```

The array is being set in the PHP file rather than passed in. It's being set using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript

Comment: [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Just noticed the increment says is++ in the code above, but the actual code does say i++ in the script.

Comment: What version of IE are you working with? Note that `Array.forEach` was only added in IE9; earlier versions do not support it. (but there are other ways of looping through an array, so it's no big deal)

Comment: +1 to @Pedro3M : although I'd add to look at the highest-rated answer, not the accepted answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript/9329476#9329476>

Answer (score 5):

Just place this [shim from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) at the beginning of your scripts:

```
if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
      fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @founddrama What? `oO` FYI there is no difference if it is `++i` or `i++` in the last section of `for`, since this code is executed separately after last line in the `for` block.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I managed to get it working :) Had to change it quite a bit, but the links and advise provided pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again

Comment: @user2610063 If the answer helped you, you may accept it by clicking tick on the left.